# How to change symbology on layer only available on Esri REST service?

Tags: arcmap, symbology, arcgis-10.5, arcgis-rest-api

I'm trying to work with a layer I can only find from an Esri REST service and I need to change the color of the layer, as the default blue it comes in doesn't show up well against an already-established map we're adding it to. When I open layer properties, I don't see the usual symbology tab or any other symbology options on any tabs.

[image: screenshot of layer properties where no tabs have symbology options]

The symbology/legend seems to be built into the layer API from what I see at this page on the file details: https://gis.wim.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/AIR_NDGA/AIR_NDGA/MapServer

Is there an option to change symbology on layers like this? Here's the layer of interest that seems to have fixed symbology: https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/bia-indian-lands-dataset-indian-lands-of-the-united-states I have not found any other sources of this dataset other than through Esri REST API links.

One option I've explored to no avail is converting / saving the API-provided layer into a regular shapefile saved locally, figuring I could change the symbology on that.

Comment: You would need to add the individual layer from the map service, rather than the entire map service.  Ie, the layer at:  https://gis.wim.usgs.gov/arcgis/rest/services/AIR_NDGA/AIR_NDGA/MapServer/0 .  This is easy to do in ArcGIS Online, but I cannot see any way of doing this in ArcMap.

Comment: feature class to feature class [geoprocessing] will convert the data into a geodatabase you can style that normally. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/conversion/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm or http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.5/tools/conversion-toolbox/feature-class-to-feature-class.htm